# MYSQL Wildcards Search - Sort Result Issue

Tags: mysql

I have a table of chemicals in mysql database. I would like to perform a  wildcards search like -

```
SELECT * FROM chemical WHERE chemical like '%toluene%'
```

SQL query result is -

```
Bromotoluene
Chlorotoluene (Benzyl chloride)
Cymene (Isopropyltoluene)
Dinitrotoluene (DNT)
Isopropyl toluene (Cymene)
Octachlorotoluene
Toluene (Toluol)*
Toluene di-isocyanide (TDI)
Trinitrotoluene (TNT)
```

Can results with exact matches from the first character of the string (in this case, 'toluene') be listed ahead of any other result? For example - I would like to display -

```
Toluene (Toluol)
Toluene di-isocyanide (TDI)
```

first and then rest of the results.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: use only `%toluene`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But this will not solve my problem. I want to list all the chemical which contains the string 'Toluene'. %toluene will only display Bromotoluene and Octachlorotoluene .

Comment: If you want to score the hits, you could try full text search instead: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split the query in two parts:

```
select * FROM chemical where chemical like 'toluene%'
union
select * FROM chemical where chemical like '%toluene%'
```

In order to put the more relevant results on top. The duplicate results will automatically be excluded by `union`.

Comment: Spot on ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE info (val varchar(50));

INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Bromotoluene');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Chlorotoluene (Benzyl chloride)');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Cymene (Isopropyltoluene)');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Dinitrotoluene (DNT)');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Isopropyl toluene (Cymene)');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Octachlorotoluene');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Toluene (Toluol)*');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Toluene di-isocyanide (TDI)');
INSERT INTO info (val) VALUES ('Trinitrotoluene (TNT)');

SELECT *
FROM info
WHERE val LIKE '%toluene%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN val LIKE 'toluene%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, val
```

[Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfda4/1/0)

Comment: It does, if you change the name of the table; apparently #INFO is not accepted.

Comment: @Cynical just changed everything to MySQL.